# For loop to produce a comma delimited string of appended values

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, append

I have a script:

```
    OUTPUT_DIR=/share/es-ops/Build_Farm_Reports/WorkSpace_Reports
    BASE=/export/ws
    TODAY=`date +"%m-%d-%y"`
    HOSTNAME=`hostname`
    WORKSPACES=( "bob_avail" "bob_used" "mel_avail" "mel_used" "sideshow-ws2_avail" "sideshow-ws2_used" )
    if ! [ -f $OUTPUT_DIR/$HOSTNAME.csv ] && [ $HOSTNAME == "sideshow" ]; then
    echo "$HOSTNAME" >  $OUTPUT_DIR/$HOSTNAME.csv # with a linebreak
    separator="," # defined empty for the first value
    for v in "${WORKSPACES[@]}"
    do
      echo -n "$separator$v" >> $OUTPUT_DIR/$HOSTNAME.csv # append, concatenated, the separator and the value to the file
      #separator="," # comma for the next values
    done
    echo >> $OUTPUT_DIR/$HOSTNAME.csv # add a linebreak (if you want it)
    fi
    WORKSPACES2=( "bob" "mel" "sideshow-ws2" )
    separator="" # defined empty for the first value
    for v in "${WORKSPACES2[@]}"
    do
        echo -n  "$separator`df -m $BASE/$v | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print $3","$2}}'`" >> $OUTPUT_DIR/$HOSTNAME.csv
        separator="," # comma for the next values
    done
```

which produces this:

```
sideshow
,bob_avail,bob_used,mel_avail,mel_used,sideshow-ws2_avail,sideshow-ws2_used
470400,1032124,661826,1032124,43443,1032108
```

But I wanted the second for loop to put the date in the first column like this:

```
09-20-14,470400,1032124,661826,1032124,43443,1032108
```

meaning

```
$TODAY,<bob avail>,<bob used>,mel avail>,<mel used>,<sideshow-ws2 avail>,<sideshow-ws2 used>
```

So the overall output would look like this:

```
sideshow
,bob_avail,bob_used,mel_avail,mel_used,sideshow-ws2_avail,sideshow-ws2_used
09-20-14,470400,1032124,661826,1032124,43443,1032108
```

and if this runs off a cron then I only have to check if the hostname is x and the .csv file does exist then:

```
sideshow
,bob_avail,bob_used,mel_avail,mel_used,sideshow-ws2_avail,sideshow-ws2_used
09-20-14,470400,1032124,661826,1032124,43443,1032108
09-20-15,470400,1032124,661826,1032124,43443,1032108
```

just add the next day's values.

Comment: You want the same trick with `-n` for this. Loop over `WORKSPACES2`, run those two commands, echo them both to the file, and continue. (Actually you just need to run the command once. Use `{print $3","$2}`.)

Comment: That didn't get the date in the first column like in the first for loop for some reason. I pasted the output into my question.

Comment: You can't loop over the date like a workspace. You just `echo -n` that to the file before the loop.

Comment: Also, as an aside, you don't need two `WORKSPACES` arrays if the first is just to have `*_avail` and `*_used` entries for each person. Just use the loop of bare names and `echo -n "$separator${v}_avail,${v}_used" in the first loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there are a few simple ways to produce comma-separated lists. The one I usually use is `paste -sd,`, which requires the values to be on separate lines. That can easily be arranged:

```
printf %s\\n "${WORKSPACES[@]}" | paste -sd,
```

but if we're going to pipe `printf` through a utility, we might as well put the commas in with `printf` and delete the one we don't want:

```
printf ,%s "{WORKSPACES[@]}" | cut -c2-
```

`cut` and `paste` will both guarantee that there is a newline at the end of their output. In this case, it seems to be what's desired, but if it were not, you can use `"$(...)"` to eliminate the newline:

```
printf %s "$(printf ,%s "{WORKSPACES[@]}" | cut -c2-)"
```

Extra added bonus: produce the `_avail` and `_used` labels with a bash one-liner:

```
paste -d, <(printf %s_avail\\n "${WORKSPACES2[@]}") \
          <(printf %s_used\\n "${WORKSPACES2[@]}") | paste -sd,
```

---

Now, let's consider the df invocation. You're invoking `df` six times in order to extract individual fields using a very powerful tool (`awk`) which could do pretty well all the work for you. Let's do that. First, we'll tell `df` about all the filesystems we want, and then we can handle all of the lines as we get them, extracting two fields and outputting them with commas in between. As an extra added bonus, we can output the timestamp, too:

```
WORKSPACES2=( "bob" "mel" "sideshow-ws2" )
df -m "${WORKSPACES2[@]/#//export/ws/}" | awk '
    BEGIN  { print strftime("%m-%d-%y")}
    NR > 1 { printf ",%s,%s", $3, $2; }
    END    { printf "\n"}' >> "$OUTPUT_DIR/$HOSTNAME.csv"
```

The above assumes Gnu awk, which has a `strftime` function. With other awks, you have to invoke a shell:

```
df -m "${WORKSPACES2[@]/#//export/ws/}" | awk '
    BEGIN  { "date +%m-%d-%y" | getline date;
             printf "%s",date }
    NR > 1 { printf ",%s,%s", $3, $2; }
    END    { printf "\n"}' >> "$OUTPUT_DIR/$HOSTNAME.csv"
```

The `bash` expression `"${WORKSPACES2[@]/#//export/ws/}"` is an iterated search and replace; that is, the search-and-replace is applied to each element of the array in turn, creating a separate "word" for each element. The pattern in this case is `#` which in here means "an empty pattern starting at the beginning of the line". The replacement starts immediately after the second `/`, and we don't (and must not) backslash-escape the following `/` because bash is not expecting a trailing `/` in the replacement (and the backslashes would be copied into the replacement if we put them in). I encourage you to experiment with `echo` and various search and replace strings in order to get the hang of it.

Comment: Is there a way to put the date in the first column like I show above?

Comment: @BrianBills: Yeah, I just added that.

Comment: How do I echo your output to the .csv file? And when the cron kicks off the next day I want your output to print right below the previous bottom line.

Comment: @BrianBills: You just `>> file.csv` as normal. It's just bash.

Comment: @BrianBills: I changed it so that the `awk` program puts a new line at the end and added the appending stdout redirect. You should be able to figure out the rest, no?

Comment: On the first pass I got `awk: line 4: function strftime never defined` so I put back ticks around your date function and then I got `awk: 2: unexpected character`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61612/discussion-between-rici-and-brian-bills).

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @rici I was able to get everything to work the way I wanted:

```
    OUTPUT_DIR=/share/es-ops/Build_Farm_Reports/WorkSpace_Reports
    BASE=/export/ws
    TODAY=`date +"%m-%d-%y"`
    HOSTNAME=`hostname`
    WORKSPACES=( "bob_avail" "bob_used" "mel_avail" "mel_used" "sideshow-ws2_avail" "sideshow-ws2_used" )
    if ! [ -f $OUTPUT_DIR/$HOSTNAME.csv ] && [ $HOSTNAME == "sideshow" ]; then
    echo "$HOSTNAME" >  $OUTPUT_DIR/$HOSTNAME.csv # with a linebreak
    separator="," # defined empty for the first value
    for v in "${WORKSPACES[@]}"
    do
      echo -n "$separator$v" >> $OUTPUT_DIR/$HOSTNAME.csv # append, concatenated, the separator and the value to the file
      #separator="," # comma for the next values
    done
    echo >> $OUTPUT_DIR/$HOSTNAME.csv # add a linebreak (if you want it)
    WORKSPACES2=( "bob" "mel" "sideshow-ws2" )
    df -m "${WORKSPACES2[@]/#//export/ws/}" | awk '
        BEGIN  { "date +'%m-%d-%y'" | getline date;
                 printf "%s",date }
        NR > 1 { printf ",%s,%s", $3, $2; }
        END    { printf "\n"}' >> "$OUTPUT_DIR/$HOSTNAME.csv"
    elif [ $OUTPUT_DIR/$HOSTNAME.csv ] && [ $HOSTNAME == "sideshow" ]; then
    WORKSPACES2=( "bob" "mel" "sideshow-ws2" )
    df -m "${WORKSPACES2[@]/#//export/ws/}" | awk '
        BEGIN  { "date +'%m-%d-%y'" | getline date;
                 printf "%s",date }
        NR > 1 { printf ",%s,%s", $3, $2; }
        END    { printf "\n"}' >> "$OUTPUT_DIR/$HOSTNAME.csv"
    else
    :
    fi
```

On the first pass produces the output:

```
    sideshow
    ,bob_avail,bob_used,mel_avail,mel_used,sideshow-ws2_avail,sideshow-ws2_used
    09-20-14,470400,1032124,661826,1032124,43443,1032108
```

The second pass:

```
    sideshow
    ,bob_avail,bob_used,mel_avail,mel_used,sideshow-ws2_avail,sideshow-ws2_used
    09-20-14,470400,1032124,661826,1032124,43443,1032108
    09-20-14,470400,1032124,661826,1032124,43443,1032108
```

The third pass:

```
    sideshow
    ,bob_avail,bob_used,mel_avail,mel_used,sideshow-ws2_avail,sideshow-ws2_used
    09-20-14,470400,1032124,661826,1032124,43443,1032108
    09-20-14,470400,1032124,661826,1032124,43443,1032108
    09-20-14,470400,1032124,661826,1032124,43443,1032108
```

So that when I run this with a cron each day the date will change. Awesome job thanks @rici.